# How do I make these sets of divs responsive?

Tags: html, css

Seems like no matter what I do I can't get this particular set of div's to fill the viewport.. I've tried pushing with negative values.. but either goes past the screen. My intentions is to maintain the drop shadows.. and still fill the screen. There should be only one scroll bar and thats the one inside #divBody

I have been able to create sticky footers but i lose my header using a push div.

I really enjoy the layout of this header/body/footer layout. Hope someone could help me with this.

```css
 #mainContainer {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
    #divBody {
        margin-top: 0;
        min-height: 150px;
        max-height: 500px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #divBody,
    #divHeader,
    #divFooter {
        padding: 1px;
    }
    
    #divHeader {
        height: 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #divFooter {
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="divHeader">
            header
        </div>
        <div id="divBody" class="simplebar">
         body<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
        </div>
        <div id="divFooter">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: width 100vw, height 100vh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want the header and footer always visible and the divBody to take up the remaining space in the browser height (so the only scrollbar is on the divBody).

Here is a working example of that.  There are several `calc` to compensate for the border widths.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

body {
  height: 96vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2vh;
}

#mainContainer {
    height: calc(100% - 4px);
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
#divBody {
    margin-top: 0;
    height: calc(100% - 90px);
    overflow: auto;
}

#divBody,
#divHeader,
#divFooter {
    padding: 1px;
}

#divHeader {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#divFooter {
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="divHeader">
            header
        </div>
        <div id="divBody" class="simplebar">
         body<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
        </div>
        <div id="divFooter">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Tried this cross browser and it works perfectly. I see that you did - 4px.. this is for the margin.. but what is the - 90px for?

Comment: Header + Footer = 80px (40px each) + 2px of border (1px each) + 4px of padding (2px each); + 2px of padding on divBody; + 2px border on mainContainer.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, you need to set your `height` to `100vh` and remove the `max-height` you've set on `#divBody`. `width:100%` should suffice, no need for `width:100vw`.

The `vh` unit is a relative measurement which stands for vertical height (of the viewport). Learn more about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

```css
 #mainContainer {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 2%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 7px #292929;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
    #divBody {
        margin-top: 0;
        min-height: 150px;
        height:100vh;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #divBody,
    #divHeader,
    #divFooter {
        padding: 1px;
    }
    
    #divHeader {
        height: 40px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #divFooter {
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="divHeader">
            header
        </div>
        <div id="divBody" class="simplebar">
         body<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
            1<br>
        </div>
        <div id="divFooter">
            footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like exactly what I need. I will read on that link. Thanks for the resources and explanation

Comment: @substancev How do you mean? I have just loaded this up in Firefox and it looks the same to me as in Chrome?